# Как из Activity остановить Runable поток в IntentService

Tags: android, android-service

```
public class ChronometrService extends IntentService {

public static final String ACTION_RESUME_CLICK = "resumeClick";
public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "stopService";
public static final String RESPONSE_RESUME_CLICK = "responseResumeClick";
public static final String EXTRA_PARAM = "EXTRA_PARAM";
private static final String TAG = "ChronometrService";


private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private static long mTotalMilis;
private long mLastMilis;
private long mElapsedTime;
private long mCurrentMilis;

public ChronometrService() {
    super("ChronometrService");
}

public static void resumeClick(Context context, long totalMilis) {
mTotalMilis = totalMilis;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_RESUME_CLICK);
context.startService(intent);
}

public static void stopService(Context context) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
context.startService(intent);
}



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
if (intent != null) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, action);
    switch (action) {
        case ACTION_RESUME_CLICK:
            mLastMilis = mElapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sendUpdatesToUI.run();
            break;

        case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
            //todo stop method
        }

    }
}

private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
    mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
    mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

    responseResumeClick(mTotalMilis);
    System.out.println(TAG + " mTotalMilis =  " + mTotalMilis);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // 0.1 seconds
    }
};


public void responseResumeClick(long totalMilis) {
Intent intent = new Intent(RESPONSE_RESUME_CLICK);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, totalMilis);
LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
bm.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, хороший топик, но ответа я там не нашел,  как в конкретном случае можно остановить поток Runable из самого сервиса

Comment: Ну, наверное, что-то вроде `sendUpdatesToUI.cancel()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожелению нету такого метода,  я применил removeCallbacks()

Answer (score 1):

очень просто:

```
case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
```

Comment: Пробовал такой способо, но он не срабатывал почему то, пока я в самом методе sendUpdatesToUI не поставил флаг глядя на который метод либо выполнялся, либо делал handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);